# What easing values to use to have a smooth deceleration when scrolling stops

Tags: jquery, animation

I have the following which does a smooth scroll of the page when a button is clicked:

```
let x = 0;
$("#up").on("click", ()=>{
  x+=100;
  console.log(x);
  $("html, body").animate( { scrollTop: x }, 800);
});
```

However, the stopping of the scrolling is rather abrupt and jerky. I have a vague understanding that easing might be able to shape the animation. How can I use it to make the scrolling decelerate to a smooth stop?

Comment: do you mean like these options? https://matthewlein.com/tools/jquery-easing

Comment: Yes! `swing` seems to suit my need. I previously tried `swing` but it had no effect. Followed your link and included the `jquery-easing` library and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery library includes a set of animation pre-sets. See: [their docs](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Some of them are sampled here by this demo: https://matthewlein.com/tools/jquery-easing

From the docs, a simple animation can be added to an element by including the 'easing' option to the 'duration' property of the animation.

Like this:

```js
$( "p" ).animate({
  opacity: "show"
}, {
  duration: "slow",
  easing: "easein"
});
```

In your case, it might look like this:

```js
$("html, body")
    .animate( 
        { scrollTop: x }, 
        { duration: 800, easing: "swing"}
    )
;
```

There are two easing implementations included with the library: linear and swing (default).